# I am using between date_add for an advanced search based on a user's age, but depending on the month and year doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code which uses a cases to select an age range:

```
    //the age advance search
    switch (Request::post('member_age')):
        case '18-25':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -25 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -18 YEAR)";
            break;
        case '26-35':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -35 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -26 YEAR)";
            break;
        case '36-45':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -45 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -36 YEAR)";
            break;
        case '46-55':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -55 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -46 YEAR)";
            break;
        case '56-65':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -65 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -56 YEAR)";
            break;
        case '65+':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -9999 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -66 YEAR)";
            break;
        default:
            $age = "";
    endswitch;
```

SQL:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       users 
LEFT JOIN  friends 
ON         users.user_id = friends.friends_friend 
LEFT JOIN  friend_request 
ON         users.user_id = friend_request.friend_request_to 
OR         users.user_id = friend_request.friend_request_from 
RIGHT JOIN user_personal_information 
ON         user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user = users.user_id 
WHERE      Concat_ws(' ', user_personal_information.user_firstname, user_personal_information.user_surname) LIKE ?
AND        user_enabled = 1 
AND        user_id != ? ". $age ." ". $country ." ". $travel ." ". $occupation ." 
GROUP BY   user_id
```

Now, for example, if a user's birthdate is in 1970 it will not return any values, until they change their DOB year to either 1969 (earlier than november 30th) or 1971. How come this is doing that, and how can I fix it? I am using date as my column type

Comment: Your SQL WHERE clause is borked.  You're mixing SQL and PHP syntax together. Also, what are you trying to accomplish with your CONCAT_WS function?

Comment: join first name and second name and use an input to search for it.

Comment: My guess is that questions about birthdays are pretty wll covered. Everyone has one afterall

Comment: I tried searching with no avail hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your age range code was leaving out a year between each range. Here's a fix:

```
//the age advance search
switch (Request::post('member_age')):
    case '18-25':
        $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -25 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -18 YEAR)";
        break;
    case '26-35':
        $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -35 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -25 YEAR)";
        break;
    case '36-45':
        $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -45 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -35 YEAR)";
        break;
    case '46-55':
        $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -55 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -45 YEAR)";
        break;
    case '56-65':
        $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -65 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -55 YEAR)";
        break;
    case '65+':
        $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -9999 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -65 YEAR)";
        break;
    default:
        $age = "";
endswitch;
```